# CV written in LaTeX

Tags: data-visualization, tex

I've created a CV eager for corrections. Once it is properly written it'd be converted into a template, in order to share it with the community.

Can you suggest some starting corrections or ideas? (I'm willing to implement them by my own, if I can) A brief, compilable version is pasted below:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[margin=2.3cm,top=1.6cm, textheight=1050pt]{geometry} 
  %sets margin of text for the whole document
    \usepackage{titlesec}
     \usepackage{url}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{bold-extra}
    \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    \usepackage{microtype}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \titleformat{\section}[block]         % Customise the \section command 
      {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\filcenter} % Make the \section headers large (\Large),
                                   % small capitals (\scshape) and left aligned (\raggedright)
      {}{0em}                      % A label like 'Section ...'. Here we omit labels
      {}                           % Can be used to insert code before the heading
    \titlespacing*{\section}{1em}{1em}{1em}[0em]

    \titleformat{\subsection}{\color{Mahogany}\Large\raggedright\scshape\bfseries}{}{0em}{}
    [\vspace{0.3ex}\titlerule]

    \titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0.75em}{0.75em}
    %load icons package for mail, phone and address.

    \title{\textbf{Mr. Nobody\\[1em] \footnotesize DoB January 23, 1995 \hspace{1.3em} NBL City, NBL. \hspace{1.3em} 666666 \hspace{1.3em} 
    \url{mrnobody@gmail.com}\vspace{-1cm}}}
    \date{ }
    \author{}
    \begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \subsection*{Education}

    \paragraph{National University of X, Y.} MSc. in X Y (2012--2017). Thesis: \textit{Thermodynamics of 
    chicken in Aqueous Phase Using Computational Tools, 2017.}

    \paragraph{High School, Dr XYZW.} Graduation in Natural Sciences (2011). 


    \subsection*{Work Experience}

    \paragraph{Institute for XY Z (2018--2019).} 
    Introduction to chicken Teacher, NBL, NBL.  

    \subsection*{Projects}

    \paragraph{Hazards and Safety in the corridor (2018--2019), Coordinator.} 
    Oriented to students of the Institute of NBL. The purpose was to 
    do Xperiments, reflect upon hazard and safety in the corridor (H \& S rules) and discuss results. 
    \paragraph{webdeveloper (2018--On Going), x.}
    equis and the general equisequis site is Directed by equisen.
    The aim is producing an Orange External Resource.
    \paragraph{StackExchange Member (2017--On Going).}
    Q \& A sites. {\href{https://stackexchange.com/users/6538373/santimirandarp}{Link to profile-overview}} 

    \subsection{Language}

    \begin{tabular}{lr}
    \textbullet\textbullet\textbullet\textbullet & \hspace{1em} A, B.\\
    \textbullet\textbullet & \hspace{1em} C, D.
    \end{tabular}

    \subsection{Few Skills}

    \begin{tabular}{lr}
    \textbullet\textbullet\textbullet & A: with B, C, and D, and pandas.\\ 
    \textbullet\textbullet & Linux Shell\slash . \\
    %\item[\textbullet\textbullet\textbullet] \hspace{1em} Chemistry Laboratory Tasks.
    %\paragraph{\textbullet\textbullet\textbullet} \hspace{1em} Excel, OfficeCalc. 
    \textbullet\textbullet\textbullet & HTML, CSS.
    \end{tabular}
    \subsection{Hobbies}
    %\raggedright
    Literature and Philosophy favorite authors: B. Russell, A. Huxley, W. Whitman, J.L. Borges. 
    Poetry Channel at \href{emptylink}{YouTube}.
    Music Post-Rock. Play little violin and guitar.\\[1em]
    I've written a gutenmorgen with a short biography of Marvin Schr\"{o}dinger available 
    \href{emptylink2}{here}. 


    \subsection{Summary}

    \blindtext{3}

    \end{document}
```

---

**The output so far looks like this:**

[image]

Comment: Did you look at the [moderncv](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/) package? It's what I used, and I got some nice comments on it

Comment: i haven't, there are so many packages that i've preferred just to invest my time in creating something simple. But maybe I should...thanks! @MaartenFabré

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some minor comments:

- hyperref should be loaded after the other packages (there are only few exceptions, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/36296)
- loading `url` is not really necessary because you already load `hyperref`
- you specify too many values of the geometry package. The paperheight is implicitly given by the default value of your tex distribution, the bottom margin is set to 2.3cm, the top margin to 1.6cm and the textheight to 1050pt, this is one value too much because there no free length left to adjust. I would suggest to either remove the explicit declaration of the textheight or change margin=2.3cm to hmargin=2.3cm to make sure that there is at least one free length
- `\begin{tabular}{@{}lr@{}}` will ensure that the bullets are nicely aligned with the left boarder of the surrounding text
- using formatting instructions like `\hspace{}` in the argument of `\title{}` is hacky and can cause problems with the pdf meta data. As a quick fix you can provide an alternative string to be used in the pdf meta data with `\texorpdfstring{tex code here}{pdf meta data here}`. The clean way would be to redefine `\maketitle` and include all the formatting instructions there
- If you make your work available to the community, please consider adding version information and a suitable license. For example the LPPL (Latex Project Public License) encourages the users to rename a source file before editing it. Not having multiple different versions with the same name floating around the internet will make it much easier to help users on platforms like tex.se.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.3cm,top=1.6cm]{geometry} 
%sets margin of text for the whole document
\usepackage{titlesec}
% \usepackage{url}

\usepackage{bold-extra}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\titleformat{\section}[block]         % Customise the \section command 
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\filcenter} % Make the \section headers large (\Large),
                               % small capitals (\scshape) and left aligned (\raggedright)
  {}{0em}                      % A label like 'Section ...'. Here we omit labels
  {}                           % Can be used to insert code before the heading
\titlespacing*{\section}{1em}{1em}{1em}[0em]

\titleformat{\subsection}{\color{Mahogany}\Large\raggedright\scshape\bfseries}{}{0em}{}
[\vspace{0.3ex}\titlerule]

\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0.75em}{0.75em}
%load icons package for mail, phone and address.

\title{\texorpdfstring{\textbf{Mr. Nobody\\[1em] \footnotesize DoB January 23, 1995 \hspace{1.3em} NBL City, NBL. \hspace{1.3em} 666666 \hspace{1.3em} 
\url{mrnobody@gmail.com}\vspace{-1cm}}}{Mr. Nobody}}
\date{ }
\author{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\subsection*{Education}

\paragraph{National University of X, Y.} MSc. in X Y (2012--2017). Thesis: \textit{Thermodynamics of 
chicken in Aqueous Phase Using Computational Tools, 2017.}

\paragraph{High School, Dr XYZW.} Graduation in Natural Sciences (2011). 


\subsection*{Work Experience}

\paragraph{Institute for XY Z (2018--2019).} 
Introduction to chicken Teacher, NBL, NBL.  

\subsection*{Projects}

\paragraph{Hazards and Safety in the corridor (2018--2019), Coordinator.} 
Oriented to students of the Institute of NBL. The purpose was to 
do Xperiments, reflect upon hazard and safety in the corridor (H \& S rules) and discuss results. 
\paragraph{webdeveloper (2018--On Going), x.}
equis and the general equisequis site is Directed by equisen.
The aim is producing an Orange External Resource.
\paragraph{StackExchange Member (2017--On Going).}
Q \& A sites. {\href{https://stackexchange.com/users/6538373/santimirandarp}{Link to profile-overview}} 

\subsection{Language}

\begin{tabular}{@{}lr@{}}
\textbullet\textbullet\textbullet\textbullet & \hspace{1em} A, B.\\
\textbullet\textbullet & \hspace{1em} C, D.
\end{tabular}

\subsection{Few Skills}

\begin{tabular}{@{}lr@{}}
\textbullet\textbullet\textbullet & A: with B, C, and D, and pandas.\\ 
\textbullet\textbullet & Linux Shell\slash . \\
%\item[\textbullet\textbullet\textbullet] \hspace{1em} Chemistry Laboratory Tasks.
%\paragraph{\textbullet\textbullet\textbullet} \hspace{1em} Excel, OfficeCalc. 
\textbullet\textbullet\textbullet & HTML, CSS.
\end{tabular}
\subsection{Hobbies}
%\raggedright
Literature and Philosophy favorite authors: B. Russell, A. Huxley, W. Whitman, J.L. Borges. 
Poetry Channel at \href{emptylink}{YouTube}.
Music Post-Rock. Play little violin and guitar.\\[1em]
I've written a gutenmorgen with a short biography of Marvin Schr\"{o}dinger available 
\href{emptylink2}{here}. 


\subsection{Summary}

\blindtext{3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you may like this one: http://mrnobody.epizy.com/mrnobody/nobody.html?i=1 :)

Comment: @santimirandarp :) Nice to see that Mr. Nobody is inclusive to robots, there is so much robot discrimination on the internet - all the mean robots.txt that exclude them from reading interesting websites!